# VB.net: How do you get the date of the begining year?

Tags: vb.net

Today is 3/12/2009 and based on today's date. I want to get the start date of this year and that will be 1/1/2009. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? The reason for this is i want to get the DateDiff of today's date against the start date of today's date's year.

Jack

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

**EDIT** As Konrad pointed out, just keep it simple

VS Any version

```
Dim year As New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
```

VS2008 (with Option Infer On )

```
Dim year = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
```

VS2005 or VS2008 (with Option Infer Off)

```
Dim year As DateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank. Ken is right. It is singular but that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Depending on the version of VB you might want to specify "Dim year As DateTime" so that you don't get an Obejct variable.

Comment: Uh. Just write `Dim year As New DateTime(…)`, this works regardless of the VB version and `Option Infer`.

Comment: @Konrad, Doh!, I get so caught up in type inference that I forget the basics

Answer (score 1):

There is the DayOfYear date method in answer to your last question...

```
Dim d As New Date(2009, 3, 12)

Console.WriteLine(d.DayOfYear) '71
Console.WriteLine(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, New Date(d.Year, 1, 1), d)) '70
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim day1 As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan
    '
    ts = DateTime.Now - day1
    '
    Label1.Text = ts.Days.ToString
    'or
    Label1.Text = ts.TotalDays.ToString
```